# How to get UIView's Position in DrawRect method

Tags: iphone

I have 4 views and i am drawing circles inside these views.The user is able to move these views.How can i get the position of each view?

Comment: You don't need to know the position of each view to draw circles inside them - the drawing will be relative to the view.

Answer (score 0):

If your views are instance variables in your class you can use view.frame or view.center but your question is quite low on details so I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: I want to draw and fill a polygon using the position of views

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint origin = view.origin;
CGPoint center = view.center;
CGRect frame = view.frame;
```

All these things can be used to get what you want.