# UIView's position

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have 4 views and i am drawing circles inside these views.The user is able to move these views.How can i get the position of each view relative to the window(i mean relative to **320*480**)?
I want to draw and fill a polygon using the position of views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `frame` property of the `UIView` to retrieve its location and size. See the class reference for more information:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Example:

```
... = myView.frame.origin.x; //x-coord
... = myView.frame.origin.y; //y-coord
... = myView.frame.size.width; //width
... = myView.frame.size.height; //height
```

Comment: -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{       
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: viewController.view];//Getting the Touch Coordinate        
    // NSLog(@"%f%f",touchLocation.x,touchLocation.y);
    
    if((touchLocation.x<350)&& (touchLocation.y<440))
    {
     CGRect rect= CGRectMake((touchLocation.x)-5, (touchLocation.y)-25, 7, 7);        
     self.frame=rect;     
     [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect]; 
    }
    CGPoint a= viewController.view1.center ;
      NSLog(@"%f",a);
}

Comment: @priya: please post the code in your question so that we can understand it a lot better... Please use the "display code" option in your question section

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the position in the following way:

```
CGPoint positionOfAView = view.frame.origin;
```

or if transforms were applied:

```
CGPoint positionOFAView = view.bounds.origin;
```

Alternatively, you may want to grab the center:

```
CGPoint centerOfAView = view.center;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071112/uiviews-frame-bounds-center-origin-when-to-use-what), too.

Answer (score 0):

You have posted the same question again.([your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404673/how-to-get-uiviews-position-in-drawrect-method)) Before anybody answer's this question the same way it was answered earlier. Can you please tell,

1. Are you drawing the Circles in the view using CoreGraphics?
2. When you say 4 different views, how they are managed? Are they displayed at the same time?
3. Are there 4 View objects added on 1 ViewController?

Comment: I am doing a viewbased application and i added a subclass of UIView as DrawCircle and inside the drawrect i have given the code for drawing circle.In the nib file i have given an image and added 4 views.Initially all the views will appear with a circle because i made the views as subclass of DrawCircle.Now the user can drag the circles to anywhere.But i want to fill the area enclosed by the views with a color.

Comment: Still I am confused. You are able to move the views right on the touch events, right? And you want to fill the area enclosed by views(do you mean all four views?) with some color. do you mean only the background area of the views should be colored?

Comment: Yea, area which will be enclosed by all the 4 views

Comment: well there can be two approaches... 1. you set backgroundColor to your DrawCircle Class. This way, by default all the views will be having background color. or else,2. to calculate the frame occupied by all the views, you will need to get the frame of all the views using ".frame" property of your drawcircle objects.

Comment: I just want to know the position of each view relative to the window..can u please send me a sample code for it.

Comment: Send me your project. I will do the needful.

Comment: In your ViewController, create IBOutlets for the four views you added, make the connection and then using frame property of the IBOutlet, you can get the position of them on the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position using
`CGRect frame = [myView frame];`
But remember it will send coordinates and origin based on its parent view
And after making changes
`myView.frame = frame;`
Hope this helps....

Comment: CGRect frame = [myView frame];..This will return what? I want to get x and y coordinates of view

Comment: @Priya: frame contains origin and size. They can be used like frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y and frame.size.width and frame.size.height. Change these values as you like and set the new frame to he view. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just move a view (without changing it size), consider using the [center](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/center) property, it might be more convenient.

Here's an example, assuming your circle structure is built in a certain way :)

```
myView.center = CGPointMake(circle.x + circle.width/2, circle.y + circle.height/2);
```